# Using sscanf to parse two strings out

Tags: c, scanf

I have a semi xml formatted file that contains line with the following format:

```
<param name="Distance" value="1000Km" />
```

The first char in the string is usually a TAB or spaces.
I've been using the following to try to parse the two strings out (from name and value):

```
if(sscanf(lineread, "\t<param name=\"%s\" value=\"%s\" />", name, value) == 1)
{
    //do something
}
```

name and value are char*

Now, the result is always the same: name gets parse (I need to remove the quotes) and name is always empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Thanks, code is appreciated.

Jess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As usual, a scanset is probably your best answer:

```
sscanf(lineread, "%*[^\"]\"%[^\"]\"%*[^\"]\"%[^\"]\"", name, value);
```

Of course, for real code you also want to limit the lengths of the conversions:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() { 
    char lineread[] = "<param name=\"Distance\" value=\"1000Km\" />";   
    char name[256], value[256];

    sscanf(lineread, "%*[^\"]\"%255[^\"]\"%*[^\"]\"%255[^\"]\"", name, value);

    printf("%s\t%s", name, value);
    return 0;
}
```

Edti: BTW, sscanf returns the number of successful conversions, so in your original code, you probably wanted to compare to 2 instead of 1.

Edit2: This much: `%*[^\"]\"` means "read and ignore characters other than a quote mark", then read and skip across a quote mark. The next `%255[^\"]\"` means "read up to 255 characters other than a quote mark, then read and skip across a quote mark. That whole pattern is then repeated to read the second string.

Comment: that worked. I just need a small explanation. The first %*[^\"] gets rid of the string before the first "? then the \" is th first "... I'm getting all confused here.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the original code was that `%s` stops only after seeing a space. Hence, `name` gets `Distance"` not `Distance` as expected.